# Creating a line plot with several lines in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have 3 lines(where FÜR is the X value and TPR is the Y value) that I want to put in one graph plot in Excel:

How does it work? If I create a line plot, I only get nonsense.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW8Li.png]

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: This is how my chart looks now,thanks to @teylyn.

[image]

Comment: Welcome at superuser. What exactly you've tried. Why do you have six columns for three lines?

Comment: I want to draw the curve of three lines of data in one chart. Each line consists of x and y values, (FÜR, TPR), which is independent from the other lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a disconnect between the data and your regional settings. The data in your cells shows a decimal POINT, but the axis in the chart shows a decimal COMMA. Most likely, the data in the range is not being recognized as numeric, because it is actually text.

Replace the decimal point in the range with the proper decimal delimiter according to your regional setting. If you use German settings, then it will be a decimal comma.

Then select the data and insert a line chart. With some sample data, it looks like this in my tests:

[image]

Edit after comment: if you want to plot three lines with FÜR and TPR as X and Y values, then you need an XY Scatter chart, not a line chart. Also, you cannot select all data in one go, but you must add the series one at a time.

Select the two columns with the first data set, including the FÜR and TPR labels and insert an XY Scatter chart with line.

Next, select the two columns for the next data set, again including the top labels. Copy the selection. Then select the chart and use Paste Special. In the Paste Special dialog, tick the option to use the first column as X values. It will be unticked by default.

[image]

Rinse and repeat for the third dataset.

Comment: Thank you, by formatting the cells to text and back to numbers it works. Now the chart is showing me several lines, but what I want is three lines where FÜR is the x value in y is the value in each line. How can I do that?

Comment: I've added a suggestion.